# Can't import pytorch_lightning on Google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, pytorch-lightning

I'm using !pip install git+https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning
but when I'm importing pytorch_lightning I get the following error:

ImportError: cannot import name '_RequirementAvailable' from 'pytorch_lightning.utilities.imports' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/imports.py)

It all worked fine a week ago...

Comment: Looks like a new addition, I've reversed to version 1.6.4 and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

When you install Lightning as

```
pip install git+https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning
```

you get the latest version in **development**. It is not an official release. I recommend installing

```
pip install pytorch-lightning
```

to get the latest **stable** release. I suspect this will solve your import error.

Answer (score 0):

this depends on the version, try:

```
pip install pytorch-lightning==1.8.4
```